# Why is Swift ignoring variable changes throughout the entire code?

Tags: swift, firebase, variables

So, I'm working on the SignUp page in my app.
Right now, I'm detecting errors and showing alerts if anything went wrong.

This is a simple example of how I'm doing it:

```
if username == "" {
    errorArray.append("didnt go through")
} else {
    errorArray.append("made it through")
}

if errorArray.contains("didnt go through") {
    accessGiven = false
} else {
    accessGiven = true
}
```

By the way I'm using `accessGiven` as the variable that changes throughout the code. Also, the actual code is using `.append(1)` or `.append(2)`.

Here is the full code:

```
    @IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if imageView.image == nil {
            alerts(title: "Ooops...", message: "Please select a profile picture.")
            accessGiven = false
            accessArray.append(+2)
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
            accessArray.append(+1)
        }

        if usernameField.text == "", emailField.text == "", password.text == "", comPwField.text == "" {
            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Please fill out the fields.")
            accessGiven = false
            accessArray.append(+2)
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
            accessArray.append(+1)
        }

        if usernameField.text == "" {
            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Username can't be blank.")
            accessGiven = false
            accessArray.append(+2)
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
            accessArray.append(+1)
        }

        Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: self.emailField.text!, completion: { (stringArray, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                self.accessGiven = false
                self.accessArray.append(+2)
            } else {
                if stringArray == nil {
                    print("No active account using this email.")
                    self.accessGiven = true
                    self.accessArray.append(+1)
                    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue.SignUp.toTabBar", sender: nil)

                } else {
                    print("There is an active account using this E-mail")
                    self.alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "There is an active account using this E-Mail.")
                    self.accessGiven = false
                    self.accessArray.append(+2)
                }
            }
        })

        // Passwords

        if password.text == comPwField.text {
            print("Passwords match.")
            accessGiven = true
            self.accessArray.append(+1)
        } else {
            print("Passwords don't match.")
            accessGiven = false
            self.accessArray.append(+2)
        }

        let email = isValidEmail(testStr: emailField.text!)
        if email == false {
            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Invalid E-Mail.")
            accessGiven = false
            self.accessArray.append(+2)
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
            self.accessArray.append(+1)
        }

        let passwordFieldTextLength = password.text!.characters.count
        let comPwFieldTextLength = comPwField.text!.characters.count
        if passwordFieldTextLength < 6 && comPwFieldTextLength < 6 {
            print("Pssword isn't longer than 6 characters!")
            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Password isn't longer than 6 characters.")
            accessGiven = false
            self.accessArray.append(+2)
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
            self.accessArray.append(+1)
        }

        ref.child("users")
        .queryOrdered(byChild:"username")
        .queryEqual(toValue:   self.usernameField.text!)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)  in
            if snapshot.exists() == false {
                print("Username not in use.")
                self.accessGiven = true
                self.accessArray.append(+1)

            } else {
                print("Username already in use.")
                self.alerts(title: "Oops", message: "Username already taken.")
                self.accessGiven = false
                self.accessArray.append(+2)
            }
        })

        if accessArray.contains(2) {
            print("Access not Given.")
        } else {
            print("Access Given")
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user,
                error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

                if let user = user {

                    let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser!.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest.displayName = self.usernameField.text!
                    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

                    let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

                    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.5)

                    let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                        imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                            if er != nil {
                                print(er!.localizedDescription)
                            }


                            if let url = url {

                                let userInfo: [String : Any] = ["uid" : user.uid,
                                                                "username" : self.usernameField.text!,
                                                                "email" : self.emailField.text!,
                                                                "urlToImage" : url.absoluteString]

                                self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)


//                                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "usersVC")
//
//                                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            }

                        })

                    })

                    uploadTask.resume()

                }

            })
        }

        print(accessArray)
```

Comment: I would recommend using `&&` in your `if` statements instead of using commas. It’s easier to tell what you mean. It might even be the root of your problem

Comment: Also, why are you putting a + in front of the 1 and 2 when you append items to arrays? I think this is causing `contains()` statements to fail.

Comment: You haven't paseted the whole function properly. That said, what exactly is getting printed?

Comment: Lastly, I would recommend putting `print()` statements in your `if` statements and seeing if they run. This helps identify what code is being run and what isn’t. If the code inside an `if` is being run and the variable doesn’t change, the error is completely different than if the code is *not* run and the variable doesn’t change.

Comment: thanks! i will try your recommendations. Also, Alex H?? Thats my name...

Comment: i put the print statement in the `checkForUsername` and it printed as expected "username already in use". That said, it still didnt add 2 to the array, which is letting the user register with somebody's username

Comment: There's a lot of code in the question for us to parse through. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is the code in your question exactly as it is in the app? If so, be aware that Firebase is asynchronous; the code outside and following a closure will execute *before* the code in the closure. For example, `ref.child("users")...observe` is followed by code that tests a var set inside the closure `if accessArray.contains(2` but that code will be called before accessArray is updated within the closure.